# CSS not working on menu

Tags: css, wordpress

I am working on a page in a Wordpress site (Pinboard child theme using Visual Composer) and cannot get rid of a border/shadow using CSS. On the page linked, on the bottom of the menu bar there is a shadow, border I cannot get rid of. Does anyone know how to get rid of this ?

I factored in maybe it was a border or shadow on the menu bar first, then thought maybe it was from the transparent images directly below the menu. None of these seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Page link: http://dbtest.destinationballybunion.ie/?page_id=2192

The CSS for this page:

```
#container {
margin: 0%;
}

#container text area {
margin: 5%;
}

entry-header.style {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}

.entry-title {
       display:none;
}

#attachment-nav a {
color: ##85531E;
}

.single .entry, .page .entry, .error404 .entry {
    margin-bottom: 5.1% !important;
    padding: 0;
}

.entry-content a img, #attachment-nav a img {
    background: none repeat scroll transparent;
    border: 0px solid #EEEEEE;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0px #EEEEEE;
    max-width: 98.5%;
    padding: 0%;
}

.entry-content a img, #attachment-nav a img {
border: 0px;
}

#access {
box-shadow: 0 0 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

#access {
border: 0px;
}

#access {
background-color: transparent;
}

access {
background: transparent repeat scroll 0 0;
}

#access {
position: relative;
z-index: 100;
}

#access a {
color: #85531E;
}

#access a {
border: none;
}

#access a {
border: 0px;
}

#site-title {
height:100%;
width:100%;
} 

#site-title, #site-description {
line-height: 100%;
}

#site-title {
margin: 0 0;
}

#site-title img {
 margin: 0;
}

#site-title img {
 padding: 0;
}

.cycloneslider-slide cycloneslider-slide-image cycle-slide img {
opacity:1.0;
filter:alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

.trailback {
height:100%;
width:100%;
}

.trailback {
background-size:cover;
}

.trailback {
position: relative;
margin-top:-51px;
}

.trailback {
border: 0px;
}

.trailbackb {
border: 0px;
}

.trailtitle {
position: relative;
margin-top: 30px;
}

h1 {
margin-left:0%;
padding:5px;
}

h1 {
margin-bottom:0.2%;
padding-right:2%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50.0vw;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 2.8vw;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 2.3vw;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 2.0vh;
}
h5 {
  font-size: 1.5vw;
}
h6 {
  font-size: 1.0vh;
}

p{
margin-left: 3%;
}

a:link {
color: #473E3F;
}

a:visited {
color: #a39a89;
}

a:hover {
color: #755521
}
```

Comment: Whats your problem? Do you want to **add** a box-shadow, or **remove**?

Comment: right click the menu bar and select "Inspect Element" looks like the issue is on line 801 in your style sheet.

Comment: thanks apaul34208 that's fixed it ! i tried overriding any original css properties such as box-shadow or border for #access, don't know why mine didn't work !

Comment: Adrian it was to remove the box-shadow, sorted not tks.